# Resizing Difference between changing `WindowState` and `DragMove`

Tags: wpf, livecharts

When I change the `WindowState.Maximized` to and From `WindowState.Normal`, some components in a Grid resize correctly, but others don't (namely a `CartesianPlot` from `LiveCharts`).

However, when `DragMove()` is called, the components in the Grid resize properly.  Looking at the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/master/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationFramework/System/Windows/Window.cs#L243) for `DragMove` is not particularly helpful, because I cannot call this when LMB is not down.

Any tricks to changing `WindowState` so it behaves more like manual resizing?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in LiveCharts.  Hooking into `SizedChanged` Property of `CartesianChart` and calling `Update(true, true);` when the view was resized in any way resolved the issue.